# Bootstrap Tabs Hover modification

Tags: javascript, css, tabs, hover, twitter-bootstrap

I altered the bootstrap tabs to work on hover and made some changes to hide the content tabs correctly.

I want it to function as a dynamic popup/flyout layer.

Now the problem is that it does not work properly when you dont hover over any content after hovering over the menu. I want it to be visible when hovering over the respective tab or over the content itself. The problem with my quick change of the original script is that it will still show the content when you leave the Tab to the left (1st menu item) or to the right (3rd menu item).

It is illustrated in the following jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/WnQvF/27/

A simple, clean solution would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `mouseleave` functions? They are the cause of your problem and it is not very obvious what you are trying to do with them. If they are removed then the tabs work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/WnQvF/32/

Comment: No, sorry for not being exact. I want it to be visible when hovering over the respective tab or over the content itself. The problem with my quick change of the original script is that it will still show the content when you leave the Tab to the left (1st menu item) or to the right (3rd menu item).